Runtime error when running samples from v8.dll
I try to run samples from v8, after compiling v8 from source. I am using VisualStudio 2022, with following options /D "V8_ENABLE_SANDBOX" /D "V8_COMPRESS_POINTERS" /D "_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0" /Zc:__cplusplus /std::c++20
#include <v8.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include "libplatform/libplatform.h"
#include "v8-context.h"
#include "v8-initialization.h"
#include "v8-isolate.h"
#include "v8-local-handle.h"
#include "v8-primitive.h"
#include "v8-script.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using std::cout, std::endl;
    // Initialize V8.
    v8::V8::InitializeICUDefaultLocation(argv[0]);
    ...

The samples build ok with v8.dll.lib. But I can't run them. I get following two runtime failures:
The procedure entry ??0?$MaybeStackArray@D$0CI@@icu_74@@QEAA@XZ in third_party_icu_icui18n.dll not found
The procedure entry ??0Locale@icu_74@@QEAA@$$QAEV01@@Z in v8.dll not found

The failures are thrown before entering function main.
I have located the above procedure entries with Dependency Walker in icuuc.dll. After undecorating them these procedures look like this:
icu_74::MaybeStackArray<char,40>::MaybeStackArray<char,40>(void)
icu_74::Locale::Locale(class icu_74::Locale &&)

I have googled about embedding v8 with VisualC++, all referred to some incompatibilities with clang and suggested to build v8 as monolith. But I changed Platform Toolset in Visual Studio to clang and to reloaded the project, and all out of the sudden nothing changed.
As suggested in v8 embedding guide the v8 fails witout an icu data file, so I copied icudtl.dat to current folder, and nothing changed.

Name decorations are tool-chain specific.  Was both ICU and V8 built with the same tool-chain?

@RichardCritten All v8 was built all at once, with same tool-chain. I searched for undecorated names in dlls, and found both in icuuc.dll. Then undecorated with DependencyWalker

You seem to have missed - was ICU built with the same tool-chain (as V8) ?

@RichardCritten  You seem to have missed - All v8  which includes ICU was built all at once, with same tool-chain

@RichardCritten Anyway, if there were problems with name decorations, I would get linker errors in first place. Also in llvm compatibility documentation I see this Clang attempts to be ABI-compatible, meaning that Clang-compiled code should be able to link against MSVC-compiled code successfully.. So, the project succeeded to compile with both, clang/msvc, but both clang/msvc failed at runtime with the same errors

The above dll compilation works and runs all ok, in the context of programs already build in v8 own compile environment. It even compiles successfully with VisualStudio, but crashes at runtime as described. It is not as trivial as it looks. This direction of investigation is still in progress, so if I have some progress I will add updates.
Two notes on 17 Jun 2024:
Note 1: 17 Jun 2024 MSVC will be unsupported after V8 version 13.0
Note 2: 17 Jun 2024 V8 will follow Chromium's lead and will stop providing infrastructure for GCC builds
I had to follow at once the steps recommended for VisualStudio, to build as a single lib v8_monolith.lib, the steps requiring the least amount of investigations so far. It requires manual changes, which permanently are modified, any change on V8 causes headaches to embedders.
MSVC has some degree of compatibility with clang, but there is no default V8 build configuration contained for this case. I decided to gather in this response the information valid for today date, because all info is fragmentary or outdated (guides as build v8 and not go mad, or Building Google v8 not too old, but already outdated), so it taken time until I put all of following together.
Note, if you compile on an external SSD drive, the depot_tools will fail to update, and none of following steps will work. So, depot_tools should be on internal HDD or SSD, and everything else can be built on external SSD.

Follow Checking out V8 source code.
As described in v8 build documentation

cd v8path\v8\v8
gn args out/x64.release.monolith

An editor will open, so enter following
# Build arguments go here.
# See "gn args <out_dir> --list" for available build arguments.
is_debug = false
target_cpu = "x64"
use_custom_libcxx = false
v8_monolithic = true
v8_use_external_startup_data = false
is_clang = true


Then as described in v8-user forum v8path\v8\v8\build/config/win/BUILD.gn, in section if (is_clang) as of now line 95, add cflags += [ "/D_SILENCE_ALL_CXX20_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS" ].

Finally build v8 ninja -C out/x64.release.monolith.
If above steps are successful, the v8_monolith.lib is contained in the generated obj subfolder v8path\v8\v8\out/x64.release.monolith/obj folder.

Now, following steps for VisualStudio 2022 Community Edition. Configuring a newly created  C++ project. It works with both, msvc and clang.

Set C++ Language Standard to ISO C++20 Standard (/std:c++20)
Add additional C++ compile option /Zc:__cplusplus
Platform toolset can be some of recent ones, Visual Studio 2022 (v143) or LLVM (clang-cl), both work.
C/C++->Code Generation->Runtime Library to be set to Multi-threaded (/MT)
Configure directories. Add v8path\v8\v8\include to C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories.
Configure Linker directories, add v8path\v8\v8\out\x64.release.monolith and v8path\v8\v8\out\x64.release.monolith\obj to Linker->General->Additional Library Directories.
To Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies add following libraries: v8_monolith.lib, Winmm.lib, dbghelp.lib

Then compiled following code from v8path\v8\v8\samples\hello-world.cc with little modifications, so far it runs ok:
#include <v8.h>
#include <iostream>

//compile with C++ flag /Zc:__cplusplus in VisualStudio
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include "libplatform/libplatform.h"
#include "v8-context.h"
#include "v8-initialization.h"
#include "v8-isolate.h"
#include "v8-local-handle.h"
#include "v8-primitive.h"
#include "v8-script.h"


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using std::cout, std::endl;
    cout << "C++: hello world" << endl;
    // Initialize V8.
    v8::V8::InitializeICUDefaultLocation(argv[0]);
    v8::V8::InitializeExternalStartupData(argv[0]);
    std::unique_ptr<v8::Platform> platform = v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform();
    v8::V8::InitializePlatform(platform.get());
    v8::V8::Initialize();

    // Create a new Isolate and make it the current one.
    v8::Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
    create_params.array_buffer_allocator =
        v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();
    v8::Isolate* isolate = v8::Isolate::New(create_params);
    {
        v8::Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);

        // Create a stack-allocated handle scope.
        v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);

        // Create a new context.
        v8::Local<v8::Context> context = v8::Context::New(isolate);

        // Enter the context for compiling and running the hello world script.
        v8::Context::Scope context_scope(context);

        {
            // Create a string containing the JavaScript source code.
            v8::Local<v8::String> source =
                v8::String::NewFromUtf8Literal(isolate, "'Hello' + ', World!'");

            // Compile the source code.
            v8::Local<v8::Script> script =
                v8::Script::Compile(context, source).ToLocalChecked();

            // Run the script to get the result.
            v8::Local<v8::Value> result = script->Run(context).ToLocalChecked();

            // Convert the result to an UTF8 string and print it.
            v8::String::Utf8Value utf8(isolate, result);
            printf("v8: %s\n", *utf8);
        }

        {
            // Use the JavaScript API to generate a WebAssembly module.
            //
            // |bytes| contains the binary format for the following module:
            //
            //     (func (export "add") (param i32 i32) (result i32)
            //       get_local 0
            //       get_local 1
            //       i32.add)
            //
            const char csource[] = R"(
        let bytes = new Uint8Array([
          0x00, 0x61, 0x73, 0x6d, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x07, 0x01,
          0x60, 0x02, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x01, 0x7f, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00, 0x07,
          0x07, 0x01, 0x03, 0x61, 0x64, 0x64, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0a, 0x09, 0x01,
          0x07, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x20, 0x01, 0x6a, 0x0b
        ]);
        let module = new WebAssembly.Module(bytes);
        let instance = new WebAssembly.Instance(module);
        instance.exports.add(3, 4);
      )";

            // Create a string containing the JavaScript source code.
            v8::Local<v8::String> source =
                v8::String::NewFromUtf8Literal(isolate, csource);

            // Compile the source code.
            v8::Local<v8::Script> script =
                v8::Script::Compile(context, source).ToLocalChecked();

            // Run the script to get the result.
            v8::Local<v8::Value> result = script->Run(context).ToLocalChecked();

            // Convert the result to a uint32 and print it.
            uint32_t number = result->Uint32Value(context).ToChecked();
            printf("3 + 4 = WebAssembly: %u\n", number);
        }
    }

    // Dispose the isolate and tear down V8.
    isolate->Dispose();
    v8::V8::Dispose();
    v8::V8::DisposePlatform();
    delete create_params.array_buffer_allocator;

    return 0;
}

